# Call method every 30 seconds unless a row exists in table

Tags: java

I have the following class which checks a database table every second to check for rows. If a row exists it will set `includeForceUpdate = true`

if the database table does not contain any rows, then I want `sendUpdate` to get called every 30 seconds from the last time it was called.

if at anytime a new row becomes available in the table then `sendUpdate` will get called immediately and the 30 second timer starts from the time `sendUpdate` got called.

The table should constantly be getting checked for new rows.

I can't wrap my mind around doing this. Would I need to use more threads?

In simple terms, I want the following to happen

`sendUpdate` should execute every 30 seconds.

However if at anytime there is a new row in the database then `sendUpdate` should execute immediately bypassing the 30 seconds wait.

```
public class Updater implements Runnable {
    private volatile boolean exit = false;
    Database db = new Database();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!exit) {
            Boolean includeForceUpdate = false;
            try {
                Long id = db.getUpdate(myAccountId);
                if (id != null) {
                    db.deleteForceUpdate(id);
                    sleepTime = 1;
                    includeForceUpdate = true;
                } else {
                    sleepTime = 30;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void sendUpdate(Boolean includeForceUpdate) throws Exception {
       //my code here for sending update
    }

    public void stop() {
        exit = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: "if at anytime a new row becomes available in the table then sendUpdate will get called immediately", how are you going to do this (if the record inserted by your java application it can be done easily, otherwise DB vendor oriented solution should be there)

Comment: Your answer is pretty unclear. What type of database framework are you working with? Why are you creating a new database instance for each `run()` method?

Comment: I'm working with JDBC, I moved the Database initialization outside the loop. Everything database related works with no issues. I'm trying to come up with the logic in order to do this.

Comment: I just found out about `ScheduledExecutorService` I think this is what I need to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using a stopwatch for the task

```
@Override
public void run() {
    Database db = new Database();
    Instant startTime = Instant.now();

    while (!exit) {
        try {
            Long id = db.getUpdate(1105349L);
            if (id != null) {
                db.deleteUpdate(id);
            }

            Instant endTime = Instant.now();
            Duration duration = Duration.between(startTime, endTime);

            System.out.println(duration.getSeconds());
            if (duration.getSeconds() >= 30 || id != null) {
                System.out.println("CALLED!");
                startTime = Instant.now();
            }

            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```